# Finding minimizer of sum of quadratic matrix form minus log(det(X))

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I am looking to solve the following problem. The first task is to comment on the convexity/concavity of the problem and then I need to compute minimizer of the problem.

$$\min f \left( \Psi \right) = ​​\left( \displaystyle\sum​​_{​​i=1}^N  y_{​​i}^T\Psi y_{​​i}​​ \right) - \log | \Psi | \quad \text{subject to} \quad \Psi \geq 0$$

---

**My attempt so far**:

The first term is a sum of quadratic forms hence convex. $-\log|\Psi|$ is also a convex function in $\Psi$. hence, the problem seems convex to me.

In order to solve it, I have taken derivative w.r.t $\Psi$ and equated it to zero which gives me

$$\sum_{​​i=1}^N​​ ​​( y_{​​i}y_{​​i}​​^T) - (\Psi^{-1})^T = 0$$

So using this, I get

$$\Psi^* =\left(( \sum​​_{​​i=1}^N​​  \left( y_{​​i} y_{​​i}​​^T \right) \right)^{T})^{-1}$$

However, I'm not too confident about this approach. Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to show that a $\min$ exists. If $\sum_k y_k y_k^T$ is not full rank then the program is unbounded.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not very sure how I can prove that a min definitely exists as there's no constraint on $y_k$'s. Any pointers in this regard?

Comment: There must be some condition, if you take all the $y_k$s to be zero then there is no solution.

Comment: There's no such condition of $y_k$'s in the given question. As far as I can think, since the constraint is that $\Psi$ should be positive semidefinite, the term $y_i^T \Psi y_i$ must be non negative.

Comment: Take the $y_i =0$, then $f(tI) = -n \log t$ which is unbounded below. No first order condition applies.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: The extension question is as follows. minimize log(sum($y_i^T\Psi y_i$)) - log$|\Psi|$ subject to $\Psi \geq 0$ . the given instruction is that "You may have to use some surrogate function and the final algorithm could be iterative in nature". Anything on your mind in this regard?

Comment: No idea. The problem has a minimiser (given above) if $\sum_k y_k y_k^T$ is full rank otherwise it is unbounded below.